# Pasta node_modules não sobe para o svn

Tags: angular, npm, svn

Tenho esse arquivo(original) da dependencia `numeral` que fica na pasta `node_modules -> numeral ->locales -> pt-br`

```
// numeral.js locale configuration
// locale : portuguese brazil (pt-br)
// author : Ramiro Varandas Jr : https://github.com/ramirovjr

(function (global, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['../numeral'], factory);
    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        factory(require('../numeral'));
    } else {
        factory(global.numeral);
    }
}(this, function (numeral) {
    numeral.register('locale', 'pt-br', {
        delimiters: {
            thousands: '.',
            decimal: ','
        },
        abbreviations: {
            thousand:"mil",
            million:"milhões",
            billion:"b",
            trillion:"t"
        },
        ordinal: function (number) {
            return 'º';
        },
        currency: {
            symbol: 'R$'
        }
    });
}));
```

mas eu preciso alterar ele para

```
abbreviations: {
            thousand: 'mil',
            million: 'mi',
            billion: 'bi',
            trillion: 'tri'
        },
```

até ai tudo bem, mas quando eu subo ele para o svn como ele não sobe a pasta `node_modules` ele não sobe minha alteração, e lá no jenkis quando são executados os scripts para rodar o projeto npm install.. build.. etc... e mandar pro servidor ele baixa a dependência original e meus números no sistema não são formatados.

Tentativas: tentei subir a pasta `node_modules` (não consegui, talvez seja uma solução mas não consegui então se alguem conseguir me mostre), tentei acessar abbreviations e altera-la em um ts que sempre executa (mas não sabia nem como acessa-la).

tenho uma solução, que seria colocar a pasta numeral fora da node_modules, mas não quero isso porque se eu precisar alterar outra...e...outra vira uma bola de neve.

Então esta ai a pergunta: Como resolver esse meu problema que ao alterar uma dependencia que fica em `node_modules` ela não ficará "salva" porque `node_modules` não sobe para o repositório?

Comment: Acho que o seu problema não é o svn, e sim o npm que insiste em sobreescrever o seu arquivo modificado com um que ele baixa da internet.

Comment: na verdade,quando chega no jenkins o npm ta escrevendo, porque se eu abro o repositorio no svn a pasta node_modules nem está lá, ou seja, ela nem ta subindo... procurei em vários lugares se tem algo desativando ela por ela ser muito grande mas não achei :/

Comment: como eu disse, eu posso colocar ela dentro do meu projeto mas se ocorrer isso em outras dependencias vai virar uma bola de neve. O melhor jeito seria eu conseguir acessar o abbreviations em algum ts que sempre executa no meu projeto, mas não tenho ideia de como vai ser isso. Se alguem souber, ficaria mt feliz kkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é aconselhado você editar alguma coisa dentro de node_modules.

Na documentação do [http://numeraljs.com/] tem a solucão "#Locales" que você precisa.

O trecho abaixo eu retirei de lá. Espero que ajude.

```
// load a locale
numeral.register('locale', 'fr', {
    delimiters: {
        thousands: ' ',
        decimal: ','
    },
    abbreviations: {
        thousand: 'k',
        million: 'm',
        billion: 'b',
        trillion: 't'
    },
    ordinal : function (number) {
        return number === 1 ? 'er' : 'ème';
    },
    currency: {
        symbol: '€'
    }
});

// switch between locales
numeral.locale('fr');
```

As I am not fluent in every locale on the planet, please feel free to create locale files of your own by submitting a pull request. Don't forget to create both the locale file (example: locales/fr.js) and the locale test (example: tests/locales/fr.js). Thanks for helping out.

Comment: ele não aceita essa criação, pois não consiste em uma nova localidade e sim um formato para se adequar ao meu projeto

Comment: Pelo que percebi você pode criar uma location "BR-custom" que lhe atenda e utiliza-la como você precisa.